# $(…).datepicker is not a function in Metronic bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker, metronic

I can't implement date picker from Metronic in my html website. It return me with the error of '$(…).datepicker is not a function'. I have tried adding datepicker plugin throught those below but non of them work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css"/>
```

My error starting at:

```
var demos = function () {
        // minimum setup
        $('#kt_datepicker_1, #kt_datepicker_1_validate').datepicker({
            rtl: KTUtil.isRTL(),
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "bottom left",
            templates: arrows
        });
```

Metronic datepicker template I use:
[Metronic Keethemes datepicker](https://preview.keenthemes.com/metronic/demo4/crud/forms/widgets/bootstrap-datepicker.html)

Comment: You do not need to include datepicker as a cdn. It should be already included, check Metronic quick start official doc: https://keenthemes.com/metronic/?page=docs&section=html-webpack-quick-start

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I already have those thing yet it still returns me with that error thus I resolve to include others plugin. Kinda an act of depression but I don't know what else to do.